# How to return a value from a custom DevExpress ButtonEdit

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I have a custom EditButton that shows a dialog for the user to select a value.

This is used by an xtra grid as an editor for a cell.
The user can click the cell editor, the dialog shows and they can select the item they want.

How do I then return this selection back to the grid?

Here is a code snippet showing the custom EditButton.
I am using DevExpress version 9.2

```
Class ClientIdEditor Inherits ButtonEdit

    Protected Overrides Sub OnClickButton(ByVal buttonInfo As DevExpress.XtraEditors.Drawing.EditorButtonObjectInfoArgs)
        dim editValue = MagicShowDialogGetEditValue()
        MyBase.OnClickButton(buttonInfo)
    'How do I return the edit value so the grid picks it up?
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the result to the [EditValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseEdit_EditValuetopic) property.

Example

```
EditValue = MagicShowDialogGetEditValue()
```